# How to do this join query laravel way

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

```
    SELECT listings.id, 
       listings.space_fullname, 
       images.image_file 
    FROM   listings 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN images 
                    ON images.id = (SELECT id 
                                    FROM   images 
                                    WHERE  images.listings_id = listings.id 
                                    LIMIT  1) 
    WHERE  listings.id = 69
```

How to do this query in laravel way without using DB::raw or DB::select?

Thank you

Comment: That will help you! https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#joins

Answer (score 1):

```
->I think listings and images are two different tables
->In both tables  images.listings_id and  listings.id may be equal
```

then below query may be useful

```
 DB::table('listings')->leftjoin('images','images.listings_id','=','listings.id')            ->select('listings.id','listings.space_fullname','images.image_file')
            ->where('listings.id','=',69)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Yes, it is different table listings can have many images but I need only 1 image for every listing

Comment: you are joining two tables with id's.Is listings_id is repeating in listings table.